# Reactive form not respecting selected dropdown value only in live

Tags: angular

OK so I have the following component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Nightshelter } from "app/nightshelter/models/nightshelter.interface";
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'nightshelter-dropdown',
    template: `
        <div [formGroup]="parent">                     
        <pre>{{parent.value|json}}</pre>
            <select #nightshelterDropdown (change)="yearChanged(nightshelterDropdown)" formControlName="nightshelterId" class="form-control input-sm">    
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option *ngFor="let nightshelter of nightshelters"
                    [value]="nightshelter.id" 
                    [selected]="nightshelter.id == nightshelterId">
                        {{nightshelter.title}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    `
})
export class NightshelterDropdownComponent {
    @Input()
    nightshelters: Nightshelter[];

    @Output()
    handleNightshelterYearChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    @Input()
    parent: FormGroup;

    yearChanged(nightshelterDropdown): void {
        console.log('changing value to')
        this.handleNightshelterYearChange.emit(nightshelterDropdown.value)
    }
}
```

The relevant result of that json pipe is:

```
{
      "id": null,
      "nightshelterId": "2",
```

My component gets rendered out as:

```
<nightshelter-dropdown>
        <div class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">                     
            <select class="form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formcontrolname="nightshelterId">    
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <!----><option value="2">
                        Nightshelter 2015-2016
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </nightshelter-dropdown>
```

The problem I am having is despite the value for nightshelterId in the reactive form and hence json is correct, my dropdown value is not being selected.

This is working perfectly locally (even when switching in production mode)

However on the server it is just leaving "Select" selected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select #nightshelterDropdown 
    [(ngModel)]="nightshelter.id"
    (ngModelChange)="yearChanged($event)"
    formControlName="nightshelterId" 
    class="form-control input-sm">    
       <option value="0">Select</option>
       <option *ngFor="let nightshelter of nightshelters"
           value={{nightshelter.id}}>
           {{nightshelter.title}}
       </option>
</select>
```

---

```
yearChanged(value): void {
   this.nightshelter.id = value;
   console.log(`changing value to ${this.nightshelter.id}`);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what has changed and why as I can't see why this would work? Where is this.nightshelter set? The problem isn't in the change event firing as that occurs and sets the form value correctly... its just not showing as selected in the UI

Comment: nightshelter  is set in the handler.. yearChanged... If you want to see something similar check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/dIS2GJdcA8OiPZU4jD4C?p=preview